# Как получить доступ к папке "tools" на рабочем столе через Filemanager в SwiftUI MAC OS для загрузки mp3 файла в audioPlayer?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Если mp3 файл добавить в проект, то все работает. Есть задача получить доступ к определенной папке, где будет порядка 10 mp3 файлов. Функция получает название файла и подгружает его в плеер.

```
func playSound(soundName: String) {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.path(forResource: soundName, ofType: "mp3") else { return }
        audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: url))
        audioPlayer.play()
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            audioPlayer?.play()
        }
    }
```

Я пробовал много вариантов, но получить путь к папке на рабочем столе не получается. Все пути при изменении в urls .documentDirectory .musicDirectory .userDirectory и других параметров ведут в проект.

```
 func playSound2(soundName: String) {
        
        let manager = FileManager.default
        let urls = manager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        if let url = urls.first {
            var fileURL = url.appendingPathComponent(soundName)
            fileURL = fileURL.appendingPathExtension("mp3")
            
            audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: fileURL)
            audioPlayer.play()
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                audioPlayer?.play()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вот так попробуйте достать файл: "/Users/username/Desktop/file.mp3"

Comment: Путь есть ```let path = "/Users/username/Desktop/tools/\(soundName).mp3"``` Непонятно как его использовать в коде.

Comment: А в чем проблема? audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))

Comment: @OlegSoloviev Строка: audioPlayer.play() - Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Убедитесь, что у вас URL корректный получается (проверьте path, URL не nil), на него ругается.

Comment: @OlegSoloviev Путь правильный, файл mp3 есть. Ответ schmidt9 прояснил ситуацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте удалить секцию `App Sandbox` на вкладке `Signing & Capabilities` в настройках таргета, по умолчанию приложение имеет доступ только к папкам внутри отдельной песочницы, при первом доступе к рабочему столу (попытке проиграть файл оттуда) у вас будет запрошено разрешение для доступа, вот пример проигрывания файла test.mp3 с рабочего стола

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Play") {
            playSoundFromDesktop(soundName: "test.mp3")
        }
    }
    
    func playSoundFromDesktop(soundName: String) {
        do {
            guard let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSString("~/Desktop/").expandingTildeInPath)
                    .appendingPathComponent(soundName) else { return }
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: filePath)
            audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer?.play()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Все работает! У меня были подозрения что приложение имеет доступ только к своим папкам. Но информацию по этому вопросу в сети я не нашел. Ваш ответ очень полезный!

Comment: @Mayskiy информации много по запросу cocoa app sandbox, например https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-application-sandboxing/